# Magento2.3.5 - Fastest way to check if product got related products

Tags: magento2.3, related-products, magento2.3.5

At the moment we use the following code on the product page, to check If the product got related products or not. But this is quite a slow method and slows the product page down with more than 0.5 sec.

Is there a faster way to check If the product got related products?

**CODE**:

```
<?php $relatedProduct = $product->getRelatedProducts(); if (!empty($relatedProduct)):?>
   GOT PRODUCTS
<?php endif;?>
```